# NoneType' object has no attribute 'split

Tags: split, attributes, jython, attributeerror, nonetype

Im using Jython on Soatest Parasoft and getting error when I'm ruining my test
the test is for calling an API to get the response then compare with DB.
test individually validated and both DB results and API response are working fine.
the Jython code has written as custom method for comparison

```
 from com.parasoft.api import *

  def compareResults(input, context):

    actual = context.getValue("Generated Data Source", "Actual_goalId")

    expect = context.getValue("Generated Data Source", "Expected_goalId")

    actual_arr = []
    expect_arr = []

    actual_arr = actual.split(",")

    expect_arr = expect.split(",")

    if len(actual_arr) == len(expect_arr):

        for e_pointer in expect_arr:

            a_pointer = 0

            final_result = 0

            for a_pointer in actual_arr:

                if str(a_pointer) == str(e_pointer):

                    final_result = 1

                    break

            if final_result == 0:

                Application.showMessage("-------->From actual results: " + str(e_pointer) + " is missing")

                break

            else:

                Application.showMessage("-------->From actual results: " + str(e_pointer) + " is present")

    else:

        Application.showMessage("-------->The numbers of goal ID does not match what retrieved from data base")              

    Application.showMessage("Actual goal ID is " + str(actual_arr))

    Application.showMessage("Expected goal ID is " + str(expect_arr))

    return final_result
```

what is solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you try to print  actual and expect? 
Like in your code:

```
Application.showMessage(" Content of actual  : " + str(actual))
Application.showMessage(" Content of expect : "  + str(expect))
```

Or try to use built-in type()

```
type(actual)
```

or check if it is NULL

```
actual is None
```

It looks that you may have NULL  in one of your data sources, or your data source "is NULL"

Please, verify that the "**Use data source**" check box is selected in Parasoft SOAtest Extension Tool **and that the correct Data Source is selected in the Data Source combo box**.
In your code you are using data source name "Generated Data Source" and I'm not sure if you actually have such name, so it also might be a reason of having NoneType/NULL.

In other words, I suppose that your code might be correct, however configuration of Extension Tool and eventually data source name is wrong.

Comment: You can also use isinstance()

Comment: Im getting this error when im running it; sometimes from line 14 sometimes from 12:
Message: Error during script execution.  View Details for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in compareResults
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
But Ideally should print the actual response from API and expected result from DB
I already checked the Use Data source and "Generated Data Source" is the default parasoft datasource when you using databank

Comment: You have to check if your inputs from data source "Generated Data Source" are NoneType. It means that you have problem with project configuration in Parasoft SOAtest. You may publish screenshot of data source configuration and maybe publish here simple use case to recreate this behavior with your SOAtest's project. Or contact Parasoft Support.